# Maximum of $F(x,y)=(2x^2-y)(y-x^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I'm trying to find a maximum of the function 
   $F(x,y)=(2x^2-y)(y-x^2)$
by finding the value of x and y that makes the partial derivatives equal to zero.
I get x=0, y=0.
But if I try other values of x and y I can find both higher and lower values  of F.
For example
F(0,-10)= -100
F(3,11)= 14

So, the point (0,0) is neither a maximum nor a minimum.

How can I find then find the maximum on this (or similar) functions? (at least a local one).

The Hessian at (0,0) is zero.

Comment: You've found the one critical point and it's neither a minimum nor a maximum.  Why do you think there is a maximum?

Comment: $F\left(x,\frac32x^2\right)=\frac14x^4$

Comment: In case anybody is interested I've found this equation is called "Peano Surface"

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
\begin{align*}
    f(x,x^2+1) &= (2x^2-(x^2+1))((x^2+1)-x^2) = x^2 -1 \\
    f(x,0)     &= (2x^2-0)(0 - x^2) = -2x^4
\end{align*}
So $f$ has arbitrarily large positive values and arbitrarily large negative values.  Therefore there is no global maximum or minimum.

As for local maxima and minima, they would have to be at critical points.  You have found the only critical point and it isn't an extremum.

Comment: In fact I have only calculated the first derivatives, but I think I should keep derivating till the first derivative different to zero. And check the parity....

Answer (score 0):

The function has neither minima nor maxima.
Further , after getting stationary value

You didn't check the condition
$$rt-s^2<,=,>0$$
Where 
$$r=\frac{d^2F}{dx^2} , s=\frac{d^2F}{dxdy}, t=\frac{d^2F}{dy^2}$$

If you are getting $rt-s^2=0$ , further investigation is required to find out whether there is maximum is minimum at $(0,0)$ or not.

Comment: This is what I said "The Hessian at (0,0) is zero."
And, as I also said to Matthew, in that case you need to keep getting derivatives of higher order.  It gets more difficult.